# How not to use 'this' in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to Angular and I'm trying to follow JSLint ( written by Douglas Crockford ) recommendation of not using `this` in JS at all.

How can I prevent myself to use `this` in Angular? All the tutorials I've seen so far rely on using `this` and SO search had resulted in no answer.

For the purpose of being clear, let's assume I'm trying to write this controller:

```
app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.products = {};
});
```

How can I access the controller object so I can add the `products` property?

```
var my_controller = app.controller('StoreController', function() {
});
my_controller.products = {}; // Maybe like this?
```

Comment: Angular (and most other frameworks) will not work with that recommendation.

Comment: Well first off, `this` is not used in controllers by standard.  You use `$scope`, you inject `$scope` into your controller and use it exclusively.  The only time I ever use `this` is in a service.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `this`, as long as you use it appropriately.

Comment: Don't follow JSLint blindly

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers#answer-14168699) can be helpful in scenarios. (pun intended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `$scope`, for example:

```
app.controller('StoreController', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = {};
});
```

Here is more information about them: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

---

Also, when using things like services, you can avoid `this` by keeping a local state and returning an interface object. For example:

```
.service('MyService', function(){
    // state
    var mystate = {};

    // interface object
    return {
        someExposedFunc: function(){

        }
    };
});
```

---

I would just like to note though, that I don't see any good reason why you should avoid `this` when using angular. I think using `$scope` has more semantic usefulness when reading controller code, but when using things like services, I write less code by creating exposed functions like `this.somefunc = ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In JS, he had decent reasons not to use 'this'. I had the assumption that it applies to Angular, or any other JS framework. Based on your reply and other people's comments, apparently it doesn't.